# Mathematical Induction clarification

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

Use Mathematical Induction to prove that

$$1 \cdot 3 + 2 \cdot  4 +  3 \cdot  5 + \ldots + (n - 1) \cdot  (n +1) = \dfrac{n(n-1)(2n + 5)}{6}$$ 
for all integers $n \geq 2$.

Base step is simple and true, but, I'm struggling to grasp the inductive step.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Compute
$$\dfrac{n(n-1)(2n+5)}{6} + n(n+2).$$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: In the second step we assume that formula

$$
(1 \cdot 3) + (2 \cdot 4) (3 \cdot 5) + \dots + (n - 1) \cdot (n +1) = \frac{n(n-1)(2n + 5)}{6}
$$

holds for $n = k$ and from there demonstrate that it also holds for $n = k+1$:

\begin{align}
(1 \cdot 3) + (2 \cdot 4) (3 \cdot 5) + \dots + (k - 1) \cdot (k +1) & =  \dfrac{k(k-1)(2k + 5)}{6}
\\ 
(1 \cdot 3) + (2 \cdot 4) (3 \cdot 5) + \dots + (k - 1) \cdot (k +1) + k  \cdot (k + 2) & =  \dfrac{k(k+1)(2k + 7)}{6}
\end{align}

Since we know that: 
$$(1 \cdot 3) + (2 \cdot 4) (3 \cdot 5) + \dots + (k - 1) \cdot (k +1) = \dfrac{k(k-1)(2k + 5)}{6}$$ we can add $k\cdot(k+2)$ to both sides of the equation:

\begin{align}
(1 \cdot 3) + (2 \cdot 4) (3 \cdot 5) + \dots + (k - 1) \cdot (k +1) + k  \cdot (k + 2) & = \dfrac{k(k-1)(2k + 5)}{6} + k  \cdot (k + 2) \\ 
& = \dfrac{k(k-1)(2k + 5) + 6 k  \cdot (k + 2)}6 \\
& = \dfrac{k}{6}\big((k-1)(2k + 5) + 6(k+2)\big) \\ 
& = \dfrac{k}{6}\left(2k^2+9k+7\right )  \\ 
& = \dfrac{k(k+1)(2k + 7)}{6} 
\end{align}

Comment: yeah but how is the final answer written highlighting that using mathmatical induction P(n) is indeed true for n>=2?

Comment: @plushy I don't think I understand your question. What is $P(n)$? Also, I pretty much wrote out the entire proof, what is the answer are you talking about?

Comment: @plushy have you tried to see what happens with $n=0$ and $n=1$?

Comment: Also try to write it as the sum $\sum_{i=?}^{n}(i-1)(i+1)$